# How to export to SVG from Illustrator using Artboards

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, svg

I am designing some icons. To keep the proportions correct, I designed all the glyphs in one artboard.

Now, I want to experiment a little with SVG icons, so I want to export these icons to different SVG files. How do I go about doing this?

I thought that I'd surround each icon with an artboard, then exporting would be easy... Turns out that the **Export** option has the 'artboards' option, but does not present any workable vector format. The **Save for the Web** also has the artboards option, but again, only offers gif, jpeg and png formats. The **Save-as** option does let me save as SVG, but does not offer any way to save the icons into different files.

Also, I have like 150+ icons, so I can't use artboards anyways (CS6 restricts me to 100 artboards only). So I tried to use slices, but where do I go from there?

Any pointers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Illustrator CC - the `Save As` dialogue has a `Use Artboards` checkbox. Checking this will save each artboard as a separate SVG file (don't forget to select SVG format).

If you have more icons than available artboards, I'd probably just copy/paste the excess into a new Illustrator document.

Source: http://creativedroplets.com/export-svg-for-the-web-with-illustrator-cc/

Comment: ... and I'm still banging my head for not spotting the "Use Artboards" option in Save As. -_-

Thank you :)

Comment: While this was the path I naturally went down, I'm not seeing SVG as a format option. Any ideas?

Comment: I see the `Use artboards` and the choice for `All` or `Range` at the bottom of the `save-as` dialog box, but when I save... then are blank. : (

Comment: Even I'm facing this problem in Illustrator CC. I checked the exported SVG, and there is no path data at all, just the `<svg>` root element, the `fill` and `stroke` colours, and that's all. No `<line>`, `<circle>` or anything like that. It was working perfectly in CS6

Comment: There is a bugfix release for CC 2015 that fixes this problem: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/kb/illustrator-cc-2015-crash-bug-fixes-19-0-1.html

Comment: In CC 2017 there is also "Export for Screens" which has choice between Artboard and Full Document, where 'full' seems to mean trim svg viewbox to fit the displayed features.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this script https://gist.github.com/TomByrne/7816376/

It export layers in Illustrator in separate SVG.

Comment: Wow! I'll give this a try... hope this works well!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with export section for each svg

Comment: The op mentioned that there is no vector format for the export. Can you name program version and add a screenshot showing the needed option?