# Illustrator exporting to SVG, with correct filename while keeping my original .ai file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a file called website_assets.ai that will have about 20 artboards. Each artboard contains a graphic element such as a symbol, logo or a button.

Each artboard has a name such as: symbol, logo or button. I want to export each of these artboards as their respective .svg file. To do this I currently go to File > Save a Copy, change Save as Type to SVG (*.svg) and select "Use Artboards" I then click Save.

The files that are saves are:

- website_assets copy_symbol.svg
- website_assets copy_logo.svg
- website_assets copy_button.svg

But what I really want is to export files with this convention:

- symbol.svg
- logo.svg
- button.svg

...while I still have my big .ai file that lists all of the artboards.

What do I need to do to achieve this?

I read the Accepted Answer here: [How to export to SVG from Illustrator using Artboards](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36725/how-to-export-to-svg-from-illustrator-using-artboards) and if I follow those instructions and select, "Save As" and choose SVG (*.svg) and then select "Use Artboards", and click "Save" then the opened file changes to an SVG and I no longer have my big .ai (or even svg) file that lists all of the artboards.

My About Illustrator dialog says I am using version 20.1.0.

Comment: Does it still append 'Copy' to the filenames if you save in a folder that does not already contain the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the export feature at "File > Export > Export for Screens" would be what you need to use instead. [image: Export for Screens - screen grab]

The labels next to the icons are the title of each artboard. The gear, I outlined it with a red box in screen grab above, allows you to specify a few export options for each file type. With **Export for Screens**, you can export multiple file types at different sizes, add a suffix for each type, and a prefix to all the exports.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This is the perfect answer in this case because rlsaj already has the Artboards named correctly... No prefix/suffix is needed because they want the filenames to correspond exactly to the names of the Artboards. +1